# Which would be more efficient, having each user create a database connection, or caching?

Tags: html, mysql, performance

I'm not sure if caching would be the correct term for this but my objective is to build a website that will be displaying data from my database.

My problem: There is a high probability of a lot of traffic and all data is contained in the database.

My hypothesized solution: Would it be faster if I created a separate program (in java for example) to connect to the database every couple of seconds and update the html files (where the data is displayed) with the new data? (this would also increase security as users will never be connecting to the database) or should I just have each user create a connection to MySQL (using php) and get the data?

If you've had any experiences in a similar situation please share, and I'm sorry if I didn't word the title correctly, this is a pretty specific question and I'm not even sure if I explained myself clearly.

Comment: You don't need some java program constantly writing html. Why not just rebuild the necessary html elements on add, update, and delete? Depending on how the site is built this is pretty easy to manage. But having many users connecting to databases is not like it is straining the system unless you didn't build the DB correctly or are experiencing enormous traffic - like millions of hits. No site just starts that way so you may want to cache when you can, but use the DB for what it's for. When you need to scale, do so. But don't over-engineer in the beginning.

Comment: well I know over-engineering in the beginning is not a good idea, but the website (hasn't been built yet), is expected to have a large amount of traffic immediately, and then slow down over a period of time. I just don't want the database to fail when traffic is at peak (and peak would be in the millions of hits per day). Also the database is never altered by the viewers (no registration, comments, etc) so its only containing information to be displayed, never altered.

Comment: If the database never alters, why not just use it once to generate the html you need and serve flat text then? And what exactly is "large traffic" - like a million hits per minute? And how can you be so confident that will happen? - sorry - a million per day might not bee too bad on the system depending on the host. are you using a virtual dedicated environment, shared hosting, single dedicated server, etc

Comment: the database will be altered, but not by the website where traffic will be coming in (maybe a new entry every minute or so), however the reason for my concern is that my previous website (same story, got around 4million pageviews/day - just checked analytics) crashed within a few minutes of me installing phpbb on it because of the database server.

Comment: @Cody How ofter will your tables be updated? inserts/deletes/updates  also can you please tell me what is the output of this SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_type';

Comment: You should update this post to include phpbb as a tag. You know that's not the most stable or high performance software to begin with. But being it is third party, they may have their own caching plugins already. None the less, you can still hook into add/edit/delete and rebuild html then, even if it is not user altered

Comment: @Kai well phpbb was an example, i dont have any intentions of using it for the new site (that was the old one), do you have any better recommendations though? for future.

Comment: @Mike query_cache_type is ON

Comment: It depends. If a forum, phpbb might be fine in the right environment. But if your site is not a forum, which your description sounds like it is not, then phpbb would be an illogical choice since it wouldn't utilize the forum features. if you're writing flat text, then a custom solution makes sense. In most cases wordpress with caching would suffice. But obviously all of this requires knowing the scale and needs of the site. Hard to say with limited information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some thoughts for you to think about.

First, I do not recommend you create files but trust MySQL. However, work on configuring your environment to support your traffic/application.

You should understand your data a little more (How much is the data in your tables change? What kind of queries are you running against the data. Are your queries optimized?)

Make sure your tables are optimized and indexed correctly. Make sure all your query run fast (nothing causing a long row locks.)

If your tables are not being updated very often, you should consider using MySQL cache as this will reduce your IO and increase the query speed. (BUT wait! If your table is being updated all the time this will kill your server performance big time)

Your query cache is set to "ON". Based on my experience this is always bad idea unless your data does not change on all your tables. When you have it set to "ON" MySQL will cache every query. Then as soon as they data in the table changes, MySQL will have to clear the cached query "it is going to work harder while clearing up cache which will give you bad performance." I like to keep it set to "ON DEMAND"
from there you can control which query should be cache and which should not using `SQL_CACHE` and `SQL_NO_CACHE`

Another thing you want to review is your server configuration and specs.
How much physical RAM does your server have?
What types of Hard Drives are you using? SSD is not at what speed do they rotate? perhaps 15k?
What OS are you running MySQL on?
How is the RAID setup on your hard drives? "RAID 10 or RAID 50" will help you out a lot here.
Your processor speed will make a big different.

If you are not using MySQL 5.6.20+ you should consider upgrading as MySQL have been improved to help you even more.
How much RAM does your server have? is your `innodb_log_buffer_size` set to 75% of your total physical RAM? Are you using innodb table?

You can also use MySQL replication to increase the read sources of the data. So you have multiple servers with the same data and you can point half of your traffic to read from server A and the other half from Server B. so the same work will be handled by multiple server.

Here is one argument for you to think about: Facebook uses MySQL and have millions of hits per seconds but they are up 100% of the time. True they have trillion dollar budget and their network is huge but the idea here is to trust MySQL to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot of useful information (I wasn't aware facebook used MySQL). Ill look into all of this, the server will most likely be quite powerful (16gb RAM, dedicated, 2xIntel Quad processors) so I think you're right, it should handle it fine. Would there be any disadvantages to using my method (using a separate program to update the html files?)

Comment: (Ill do it with MySQL, I just want to have a plan b ready just in case)

Comment: If you can bump up your physical ram go for it. Your plan b should be replication to another server where you can move the load on multiple servers. Plus make sure you carefully change ur server mysql

Comment: yah i tried that with my last project, was a mess, it worked but god it was such a mess, i was just wondering why my plan b isnt being done (if data isnt manipulated from the site itself) it seems logical to have 1 connection every couple of secodns than couple hundreds of connections every second, doesnt it?

Comment: Well you can get the same thing with query cache. Let's say your data is changing every minute and you have 1000 visits per minute then you will only have 1 hard hard query and the rest will read directly from the cache which will be super fast "assuming all the queries are the same". If your issues with the number of connections open. You should increase the max_connection allowed in mysql and make sure you script terminate the connection after it finish with the query.